# Can Unicode characters be programmatically defined in python 3.7?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a python 3.7 function that prints the Unicode character for a playing card (using [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode#Block) as a reference).

Each of the Unicode character is a string that can be represented as `'\U1F0{SUIT_ID}{VALUE_ID}'`. For instance, `'\U1F0A1'` is the ace of spades .

My code is

```
def print_card(suit_id, value_id):
    print(f'\U1F0{suit_id}{value_id}')
```

Theoretically, the command `print_card('A', '1')` would then print the ace of spades. The command `print_card('C', 'D')` would print the queen of diamonds.

However, attempting to define this function results in the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-32-b19e42821b25>", line 2
    print(f'\U1F0{suit_id}{value_id}')
         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`chr` function creates a character from a numeric code point](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> suit_id = 0xA0
>>> value_id = 1
>>> print(chr(0x1F000 + suit_id + value_id))
```

You can't process generated escape *strings* without [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval) or [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#compile) or [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#exec), but this is the function made for exactly your purpose.

If you're really keen on the string inputs, `int('A0', 16)` will give you the numeric value of `0xA0` (or `int('A', 16) * 16`), and `int('1F0{}{}'.format(suit_id, value_id), 16)` would also work for the closest match.